# Get array from json

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I m trying to access `chats` from the JSON below.

```
{"count":41,"count_id":5,"pic":null,"chats":[{"id":13,"user_id":1,"yiinput_id":5,"chat":"i like to say hello"},{"id":14,"user_id":1,"yiinput_id":5,"chat":"another chat here"}]}
```

Tried like this:

```
console.log( data );
console.log( data[chats] );
console.log(data[0].chats);
console.log(data[0].chats[0]);
```

Comment: `console.log(data.chats);`

Comment: I ll check ... but i m sure i tried it. Just forgot to add it to the question.

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.parse(data).chats);`

Comment: JSON.parse ... that's what I was missing. Add it as an answer.

Comment: done.... glad to help you :)

Comment: Thank you! Glad you helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an object then you can get the value by using `data.chats`, in case it's string then you need to parse the json string using **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** to convert it to object.

```js
var json = '{"count":41,"count_id":5,"pic":null,"chats":[{"id":13,"user_id":1,"yiinput_id":5,"chat":"i like to say hello"},{"id":14,"user_id":1,"yiinput_id":5,"chat":"another chat here"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.chats);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data).chats);
```